# So Have GetOrgChart sold to Balkan Graph as OrgChartjs?

Tags: getorgchart

So Have GetOrgChart sold to Balkan Graph as OrgChartjs?

Looks like it but the two products are incompatible.

Would be nice for someone in either of these two companies to explain the full situation so that customers can make informed decisions.

The product support from GetOrgChart was not really very good (notice how many questions here got an answer!)

The Enterprise version is not a cheap product and the documentation and information provided is sparse to say the least.

Also, valued features in GetOrgChart (Like MIXED_HIERACHY) seem to be completely missing from the Balkan Orgchart.js and the leaf structure has somewhat changed.

Come on team.... how about some details... what, why, when, how... has changed and how can we best accomodate. Also, is GetOrgChart now going to be phased out and or discontinued altogether? What is the roadmap?

Any insight here might help me know if I have wasted my money.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

[GetOrgChart](http://getorgchart.com) is 10 years old product and has many clients using it, implementing new features is a risk, so we created new product called [OrgChart JS](https://balkangraph.com) with most requested features, like PDF export, grouping, assistant support, lazy loading for better performance, etc.

OrgChart JS is a new product developed by the same company. It has completely different API so migrating from GetOrgChart to BALKANGraph will require development effort

All new features will be implemented only in OrgChart JS

If you are working on a new project my suggestion is to use OrgChart JS, if you are existing customer still you can use GetOrgChart

MIXED_HIERACHY is working well now in the latest version of OrgChart JS